# How to change Newsletters UnsubscribeLink text

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I am using macro as **`{%UnsubscribeLink %}`** to unsubscribe from newsletters.

I want to change the text of this link when a user received newsletters.

This time it is shown as '**Unsubscribe**'. How to change this text value?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different macro that returns only the unsubscription URL and create the unsubscription link text on your own.

Exact macro depends on Kentico Version. This is surely working on v11/v1.

```
<a href="{% EmailFeed.UnsubscribeFromEmailFeedUrl #%}" target="_blank">YOUR TEXT</a>
```

More complex

```
<td>
  We hope you found this message to be useful.
  However, if you&#39;d rather not receive these emails in the future,
  please <a href="{% EmailFeed.UnsubscribeFromEmailFeedUrl #%}" target="_blank" 
  style="color: #000000;">unsubscribe</a> from this newsletter.
  You can also unsubscribe from <a href="{% EmailFeed.UnsubscribeFromAllEmailFeedsUrl #%}" target="_blank" style="color: #000000;">all marketing emails</a>.
</td>
```

[Link to official documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k12/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-email-marketing/integrating-email-feeds-into-sites)